# How to make a list of editfields in Black Berry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, listfield, blackberry-editfield

I want to create a BlackBerry screen with a list of thousands of editable fields. Please give me some ideas of how to do this efficiently.

Comment: We need a problem to provide solutions. Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't add `editField in ListField`. Yes If you want to make that kind of screen use `HorizontalFieldManager` and the `EditFields`. Also See this link to get More Idea

[Place EditField in Listfield](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Place-EditField-in-Listfield/m-p/1234801#M168304) .

Comment: I know we can't add editfield in listfield. But I want to know another ways to make a list of editfield (may be a thousand of editfields) with minimum memory used. We only allocate memory for visible fields on screen. How can we do that? Thanks for your reply!